# Is there a difference between es6 class members when just having a function name?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Is there a difference between these two function declarations in an es6 class? Is the scope this same (this)? Is one way preferred?

```
class Node {
   // function declaration 1
   test () {

  }
  // function declaration 2 
  test = () => {

  }
}
```

Comment: second way is fat array, and yes it's allowed. I'm seeing it in code lately, wondering if it was FOR that reason scoping differently.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not sure I follow--this is a very common Babel transform (instance properties) and it's done explicitly to bind "this". Or are you just making the point that it's a transform and not standard JS yet?

Comment: The method declaration will add the `test` method to the `Node.prototype`. The second way, the [class property proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) is not yet part of the standard, and it will create a bound function property to each instance.

Answer (score 1):

The second way creates an instance function

```
class Node {
  test = () => {
  }
}
```

is the same as

```
class Node {
  construtor() {
    this.test = () => {
    };
  }
}
```

So effectively it is created a new function, bound to the new object's instance, every time an object is created. It's just a shorter way to say it.

The advantage is you can pass those methods to a callback. Example

```
class Node {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  test1 = () => {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  test2() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
}

const node = new Node('foo');
setTimeout(node.test1);   // works
setTimeout(node.test2);   // fails will have wrong this
setTimeout(node.test2.bind(node));   // works
```

Note that when to use an arrow function on a method and when not to is really up to the situation

```
const node = new Node('foo');
someElement.addEventListener(click, node.test1);
```

In the case above when the event listener is called `this` will reference `node`. If that's what you want great but event listeners have `this` set to the element they're attached to, in this case `someElement` so you lose that. If you didn't need it great. If you did need it then an arrow function was the wrong thing to use.